# Pl/sql script to compute the free space in the users tablespace in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, tablespace

```
SELECT tablespace_name, sum(bytes)/1024/1024 "MB Free"
  FROM dba_free_space 
 WHERE tablespace_name = 'USERS'
 GROUP BY tablespace_name;
```

Hi everyone, the above query is what i use for showing the free space in user tablespace but how do i write a separate **PL/SQL** script to store it in separate table with tablespace name and time stamp.

Kindly help me as i need this run on job scheduler for every hour.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've already created the table you want to store the data in, simply

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE snap_free_space
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO new_table( tablespace_name, free_bytes, collection_time )
    SELECT tablespace_name, sum(bytes), sysdate
      FROM dba_free_space
     GROUP BY tablespace_name;
END;
```

Comment: thank you so much, do u have any idea how do i run it on job scheduler every hour ?

Comment: DBMS_JOB is the internal database scheduling tool.

Comment: DBMS_SCHEDULER was introduced with 10g. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI "The DBMS_JOB package has been superseded by the DBMS_SCHEDULER package." http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD